# Could anyone help me to explain this sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I have read article about Kristen Stewart and Robert Pattison:

> I’m deeply sorry for the hurt and embarrassment I’ve **caused** to **those** **close** to me and everyone this has affected. This momentary indiscretion has jeopardized the most important thing in my life, the person I love and respect the most, Rob. I love him, I love him, I’m so sorry,” Stewart said in a statement Wednesday."

I wonder If the word, **caused**, has object which is hurt and embarrassment? And the word, **those**, refers to hurt and embarrassment in the front? And the word, **close**, is adjective?

Do I understand this sentence correctly that she causes the hurt and embarrassment close to her?

PS. I don't know how to highlight the word and If I mistake in any grammar, you can recommend to me.

Finally, thank you in advanced and I am sorry if I make you so confused with my question.

Comment: In terms of feedback: please remember to capitalize people's names and the first word of every sentence.

Comment: "Those" refers to the people (especially Rob) whom she believes she has hurt the most.  "Close to me" modifies "those" and refers to the people close to her.

Comment: @Xanne Is it possible that "close" is reduced from "those who are close to me"?

Comment: Yes, that's a good interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "caused" in that sentence is a verb that has a direct object ("hurt and embarrassment") and an indirect object ("those close to me").  Here are some similar examples:

- I like the book [that] Tyler gave to me.
- He had a speech [that] he would give to anyone who would listen.
- I was sad when I read the letter [that] she wrote to Alex.

The "that" in these sentences is optional (and you could put a "that" after "embarrassment" in the first sentence with the same meaning).

"Those" here refers to anyone that she has caused hurt and embarrassment to.  Yes, "close" is an adjective, but it's part of the adjective phrase (AP) "close to me."  When you see "those" in a sentence like this, you can sometimes insert "who are" or "that are" to connect it with the following adjective more clearly.  For example:

- I'm deeply sorry for the hurt and embarrassment I’ve caused to those [who are] in Belgium. *(I've caused hurt and embarrassment to people in Belgium.)*
- He can't stand those [who are] opposed to the Senator.  *(He is annoyed with anyone who is opposed to the Senator.)*

Putting this all together, the original sentence means that she caused hurt and embarrassment to *people who are close to her*.